How is Bhagavad Gita by Swami Mukundananda?
I'm interested in buying a good version of Bhagavad Gita, how is the one by Swami Mukundananda? Does his version align with the upanishads and vedanta? Is he unbiased in any way towards any sect?

In my opinion, interpretations are based on conjectures.  Learning Sanskrit and reading the original is the best.

Many Acharyas have interpreted Gita in their ways, I would suggest you read many Gita versions, you understand Gita after reading it many times and many versions. I would suggest the Gita by Swami Ranganathanandaji of Ramakrishna mission, Gita commentary by Adi Shankaracharya, and Gita commentary by Paramhansa Yogananandaji, you can also go through Gita by other Acharyas like Ramanujacharya, Madhvacharya etc.

Look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6loeQ6G5EaE

I really like Swami Mukundananda's work and his "Bhagavad Gita: The Song of God". I referred to the site (https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/) for several years before buying the paper copy. The one criticism I've seen is that in places he interprets "yoga" as "bhakti-yoga", which may be true. But the original Sanskrit is right there alongside the commentary (in Devanagari and romanized form). Every translated work is subject to interpretation, Swami-ji is known to put an emphasis on bhakti, and personally I don't see this as a major issue. I find it more accurate than the ISKCON translation.
